# Align without display math?

Tags: amsmath, align

Is it possible to use the `align` environment without the display math? For example, I would like `\sum` to look as if it were inline. The solution given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5547/how-can-i-write-multi-line-equations-with-alignment-in-inline-math-mode?rq=1) does not work, insofar as the summation symbols are still written in the big, display style. The `alignat` environment also produces this behaviour.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aligning in text (non-math)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33239/aligning-in-text-non-math)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the fact that `amsmath` defines big operators in a uniform way; for instance `\sum` is redefined to use `\sum@` surrounded by suitable macros.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\makesmaller}{m}
 {
  \goblin_makesmaller:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \goblin_makesmaller:n #1
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { \goblin_makesmaller_sym:n { ##1 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \goblin_makesmaller_sym:n #1
 {
  \cs_gset_eq:cc { #1@saved@ } { #1@ }
  \cs_set_protected:cpn { #1@ }
   {
    \mathop
     {
      \mathchoice { \textstyle \use:c { #1@saved@ } }
                  { \use:c { #1@saved@ } }
                  { \use:c { #1@saved@ } }
                  { \use:c { #1@saved@ } }
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makesmaller{sum,bigoplus,bigcup}

\begin{document}

Here's an inline formula $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)$
and the same displayed, with some nonsense
\[
\bigoplus_{i\in I}\bigcup_{j=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)
\]

\end{document}
```

The argument to `\makesmaller` is the list of operators you want to be treated as `\sum`.

When you'll change your mind, hopefully soon `;-)`, just remove the call to `\makesmaller`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround you can use `\textstyle` inside the `aligned` environment:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
text
$\begin{aligned}\textstyle
\sum_{i=1}^\infty&=1\\ \textstyle
\sum_{i=1}^\infty&=1
\end{aligned}$
more text
\end{document}
```

But it would be better to find better solution. It's more like a hack.

[image]

Comment: This seems to break the moment `\left(` is used. e.g. 
\begin{aligned}\textstyle
\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty&=\right) \\ \textstyle
\sum_{i=1}^\infty&=1
\end{aligned}

Comment: Put the `\right.` before the `&`. And paired `\left.` after.

Comment: @goblin [related](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5612/left-right-across-multi-line-equation) for `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting odd behaviours. Why doesn't the following code work, for example? \begin{aligned}\textstyle 
2 &= \sum_{i \in k} i + \sum_{i \in k}i \\ \textstyle
2 &= \sum_{i \in k} i + \sum_{i \in k}i
\end{aligned}

Comment: @goblin You need to put `\textstyle` right before the `\sum` symbols. Actually, @Bernard solution are much better with a custom `\sum` symbol.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a `\tsum` command, just like there exists a `\frac` command. And also an `\msum` command (medium-sized sum), based on the `nccmath` package.

Another solution would be to use the `tabstackengine` package and its `\alignCenterstack` command. Here is a demonstration of all theses possibilities, with different vertical alignments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\newcommand\tsum{\textstyle\sum\nolimits}
\newcommand\msum{\medop\sum}

\usepackage{tabstackengine} 

\begin{document}

\noindent Text
$\begin{aligned}[t]
 \tsum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}&=z\\
u+v&=w
\end{aligned}$
 \enspace more text \enspace $ \sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i} $
\enspace more text\enspace
$\begin{aligned}[b]
 \msum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}&=z\\
u+v&=w
\end{aligned}$
\enspace  more text\enspace
$\begin{aligned}
 \sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}&=z\\
u+v&=w
\end{aligned}$
\enspace more text. 

Some other text\enspace\stackMath\setstackgap{L}{3.5ex}$ \left[\alignCenterstack{
\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}&=z\\
\sum_{i = 1}^{n}u_{i} &=w }\right. $
\enspace  more text. 

\end{document}
```

[image]